# How to show data into textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

MY VIEW::

```
 foreach (TSM.Models.Tasks itm in lstTasks.Where(x => x.Project.ID == item.ID).ToList())
            {

 foreach (TSM.Models.TimeSheetData itemm in ViewBag.HoursData)
 {
 foreach (TSM.Models.Tasks itm in lstTasks.Where(x => x.Project.ID == item.ID).ToList())
                {


     <td><input class="txtTaskHours date@(Date.AddDays(i).ToString("MMddyyy"))" 
                style="width:50px;" value="@itemm.Hours" type="number" 
                id="@(itm.ID.ToString() + ':' + Date.AddDays(i).ToString("MMddyyy"))" />
     </td>
 }
```

My Controller:

```
var query = (from ts in db.TimeSheets join tsd in db.TimesheetData on ts.ID  
             equals tsd.TimeSheet.ID where ts.StartDate == thisWeekStart 
             && ts.EndDate == thisWeekEnd select new{ tsd.Hours, tsd.Date, tsd.TaskID }).ToList();
var TMSSS = (string.Join(",", query.Select(x => x.ToString())));
ViewBag.HoursData = TMSSS;
return PartialView("~/Views/TimeSheet/_TimeSheet.cshtml", ViewBag);
```

I want to show data into the `Textbox`. To show data, I am using `ViewBag` by using foreach loop to show hours in the `Textbox`.

My `Textbox` data is saved in json.
This is my json value :

```
"TaskHours" : [{
                 "ID":"f2886ec7-47d3-e711-9666-000c297c9306:12042017",
                 "Value":"25"
               }]
```

Comment: Please format your HTML properly so it is readable - as it stands you have mismatched quotation marks in your HTML, but I'm not sure if that's the problem or just a copy/paste error..

Comment: Also why are you emitting HTML directly instead of using standard MVC controls ?

Comment: I am edited..help me

Comment: When i am try my  code then this error come at foreach loop in viewbag.HoursData .::::::::::;Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot convert type 'char' to 'TSM.Models.TimeSheetData''

Comment: In your VIEW: the `type` misses an quotation mark at the end and the value of `id` uses `itm` where it should be `itemm`...

Comment: @Olafw  at the value of id itm should be because  another foreach loop for task then itm is used

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `string.Join` rows:

```
var query = (from ts in db.TimeSheets join tsd in db.TimesheetData on ts.ID  
             equals tsd.TimeSheet.ID where ts.StartDate == thisWeekStart 
             && ts.EndDate == thisWeekEnd select new{ tsd.Hours, tsd.Date, tsd.TaskID }).ToList();
// var TMSSS = (string.Join(",", query.Select(x => x.ToString())));
// ViewBag.HoursData = TMSSS;
ViewBag.HoursData = query;
return PartialView("~/Views/TimeSheet/_TimeSheet.cshtml", ViewBag);
```

Your controller assigns a `string` to `ViewBag.HoursData` and your View expects an `IEnumerable<TSM.Models.TimeSheetData>` which could be your `query` variable.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, my bad. Didn't see that you're selecting a dynamic object in your LINQ. You'll need to create a new wrapper class where to place the values from your LINQ.

```
public class MyWrap {
public int Hours {get;set;}
public DateTime Date {get;set;}
public int TaskId {get;set;}
}
```

And then modificate the LINQ:

```
&& ts.EndDate == thisWeekEnd select new MyWrap { Hours = tsdHours, Date = tsd.Date, TaskId = ts.TaskID}).ToList()
```

And finally in your View:

```
foreach (TSM.Models.Tasks itm in lstTasks.Where(x => x.Project.ID == item.ID).ToList())
            {

 foreach (TSM.Models.MyWrap itemm in ViewBag.HoursData)
 {
```

Comment: 'Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType9`3[System.Double,System.DateTime,System.Guid]' to type 'TSM.Models.TimeSheetData'.'
 this error come in viewbag.hours in foreach loop

Comment: Updated it - sorry, was my bad as I didn't recognized your dynamic object. The problem is that you're creating a List of dynamic Objects which can't be casted to `TimeSheetData`.

Comment: You could also just say `select x` instead of a new object - I pressume that the class `TimeSheetData` is from `db.TimeSheet`? Then you could of coures cast the list members to it.

Comment: my data is shown in the textbox but every textbox have same data

Comment: Could you debug the controller and take a look at the content of `ViewBag.HoursData`? The code itself should be correct.

Comment: I am debug the controller the ViewBag.HoursData value is correct but when In the view we retrieve data from controller then issue is create the textbox dont recoginize  how value comes in textbox by date. Please check my input textbox code.

Comment: This is my input textfield code:    <input class="txtTaskHours date@(Date.AddDays(i).ToString("MMddyyy"))" style="width:50px;" value="@jk.Hours" type="number" id="@(itm.ID.ToString() + ':' + Date.AddDays(i).ToString("MMddyyy"))" />

Comment: What happens if you simply use a single for-loop to print the data for debug purpose? No cascading loops, simple and clean?